# Sort number before alphabet or character

Tags: mongodb

Do mongodb has any method to sort number before alphabet or character?

For example: 1, 2, 3, 4, -
I used `collation({locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true})` and its output -, 1, 2, 3, 4.

But I expect 1, 2, 3, 4, -

Comment: Were yo able to try the below answer? Was it helpful? Can you approve if so?

Answer (score 0):

custom-sorting is the one you are looking for.

you can do it as below

```
 {
   $project:{
     "customFieldToBeCreatedForSorting":{
           $cond:[
             { $isNumber : "$FieldContainsMixedTypeData" },
             NumberLong(1111111111), //This can be customized by finding max in the previous stage
               $FieldContainsMixedTypeData
           ] 
     }
   }
 },
 {
    //$sort pipeline goes here
 }
```